# My edit function is not editing the page but rather creating a new page views.py Django

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, cs50

I am creating an edit function that should allow the user to click a link to be taken to a page where the user can edit that page.

Also, the page should be pre-populated with the existing content of the page. (i.e., the existing content should be the initial value of the textarea).

The challenge I am having is when the user clicks on EDIT, it does not populate the form with the previous entry that was made on the form, also when the user submits the edited copy, one of two things happen, if the page has the same title, it updates the content of the page however, if we edit the title, it creates a new page entirely.

This is not the behaviour that I want, can you please point me in the right direction to resolve this?

VIEWS.PY

```
class AddPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Tell us more!"
        })
    
def edit_page(request, title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        title = request.GET.get('title')
        content = util.get_entry(title)   
        form = AddPageForm(initial={"title": title, "content": content})
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", 
        {"form": form})

    else:
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect('encyclopedia:entrypage', title)
```

EDIT PAGE

```
{% block body %}

    <h1>Edit {{ title }}</h1>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% form %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
```

ENTRY PAGE

```
{% block body %}
        {{ content|safe }}

        <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:editpage' title=title %}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>

{% endblock %}
```

URLS.PY

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry_page, name="entrypage"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_page", views.add_page, name="addpage"),
    path("edit_page/<str:title>", views.edit_page, name="editpage")

]
```

Comment: What does `save_entry` does if the title already exists.

Answer (score 1):

The title is (probably) taken from the URL, so you work with the `title` parameter, not the `request.GET['title']`:

```
def edit_page(request, title):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        content = util.get_entry(title)
        form = AddPageForm(initial={'title': title, 'content': content})
    else:
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect('encyclopedia:entrypage', title)
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/editpage.html', {'form': form})
```

If you save the entry with the title, then editing the title makes no sense: since that would then create a new record. In that case you thus can remove the `title` field from the form, and work with the `title` parameter from the view parameter instead of `title = form.cleaned_data['title']`.

Comment: @Van I edited my views.py but I am having a bug, each time I edit the previous entry, it creates a new entry with what i edited instead of editing that copy. I've tried to retouch the possible errors. please help

Comment: def edit_page(request, title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        content = util.get_entry(title)   
        form = AddPageForm(initial={"content": title})
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", 
        {"form": form})

    else:
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect('encyclopedia:entrypage', title)
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/editpage.html', {'form': form})